# Having trouble pulling titles from another channel into a sidebar

Tags: relationships, title

This is what I currently have, Ive only been using ee for about 1.5 wks so I'm pretty sure I can't do what I am below. The index and and practice_dangers templates are in the same folder group but had to be in two different channels. Any help is appreciated.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="aop" disable="pagination|categories|member_data" dynamic="no"}
<li><a href="{url_title_path='practice_area/index'}">{title}</a>
    <ul>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="practice_dangers" dynamic="no" disable="pagination|categories|member_data"}
        <li>
            <a href="{url_title_path='practice_area/practice_dangers'}">{title}</a>
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </ul>
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[image: This is how it should look]

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: How are you relating channel (A) entries to channel (B) entries ? Shared categories, relationship? What you're looking to do is fairly straight forward provided we know how the 2 channels are related.

Comment: You need to use an embed for that second channel

Comment: @stuartmcd69 The first channel has an established relationship with channel B but I wasn't sure if I needed o create a second relation from channel b to channel a

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a exp:channel:entries tag inside itself, from your comment above it looks like you're using relationships. You should be using the appropriate tags to pull in the related entries. Replace relationship_field with your actual relationship field_name

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="aop" disable="pagination|categories|member_data" dynamic="no"}
<li>
    <a href="{url_title_path='practice_area/index'}">{title}</a>
    <ul>
        {relationship_field}
        <li>
            <a href="{relationship_field:url_title_path='practice_area/practice_dangers'}">
                {relationship_field:title}
            </a>
        </li>
        {/relationship_field}
    </ul>
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You can read more about relationships [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html).